# How do I change the variable name in the jquery clone script to increment?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to change the name of the variable myAuthorText and mybookText to maintain the author and his books seperate from the other authors and their books.

How I would usually do it in php is:

```
<?php
$x = 0;
echo "

        <html>
            <form action='' method='post'>
                <input type='text' name='myText.'{$x}'.[]'/>
            </form>
        </html>

    ";

?>
```

In the above code the name of myText is appended by a variable name in this case a number to show the increment (myText0, myText1, myText2... of course there is a for loop here to increment it). I want to to this with JQuery to not have to reload the page every time I want to add a new author or book. After the .clone I want it to change its name.

this is the code that I have for the books and authors in JQuery.

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="next.php" method="post">



<!--        http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery-->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
            <button class="add_field_button">Add Author</button>

            <div id="commonPart" class="commonPart">
                <br>
            <div><input type="text" name="myAuthorText[]" placeholder="Auth name"></div>

            <button class="add_sub_field_button">Add Author Books</button>
            <div><input type="text" class="bookname" name="myBooksText[]" placeholder="Book name"></div>

             </div>

        </div>
        <input name="submit" class="submit" value="Enviar" type="submit">
<!--        http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery-->

    </form>
</div>   


    <script src="../js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript">

        //http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery


    $(document).ready(function() {
        var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
        var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
        var commonPart      = $("#commonPart"); 
        var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
        var add_subButton   = $(".add_sub_field_button"); //Add sub button ID

        var x = 1; //initlal text box count
        $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                var htmlToAdd = commonPart.clone().attr("id","commonPart_"+x);
                htmlToAdd.find(".addedDiv").remove();
                $(wrapper).append(htmlToAdd); //add input box
              x++; //text box increment
            }
        });

        $(document).on("click",".add_sub_field_button",function(e){ //on add input button click
            e.preventDefault();
            if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                x++; //text box increment
                $(this).closest(".commonPart").append('<div class="addedDiv"><input type="text" class="bookname" name="myBooksText[]" placeholder="Book name"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
            }
        });
        $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });

    //http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery
    </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Just a side remark: NEVER call anything in a form `name="submit"`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `"I want to to this with JQuery to not have to reload the page every time I want to add a new author or book. After the .clone I want it to change its name"`. could you elaborate it more

Comment: @dreamweiver I want the JQuery code to change the variable name at every .clone. After the user presses the ADD AUTHOR button I want the next variable name 'myAuthorText[]' to change its name to 'myAuthorText1[]'

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: It does not work in jsfiddle.net but here is what I was working on there: 
[http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=y9kuiFuCaQ]